# How can I diagnose certain games crashing?

Tags: windows-7, crash, troubleshooting, nvidia-graphics-card

With a handful of games will crash to desktop after playing for anywhere from 15 minutes to a few hours.  There will be a visual glitch, a pause, and then crash to desktop.  If Firefox is running, that may also crash.  The games generally will not start after this and I have to reboot.

The two games are Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel and Defiance.  3DMark will also freeze after the demo and during Sky Diver.  Most other games work fine (World Of Tanks, War Thunder, Borderlands 2, Dishonored...).  Borderlands and most others are configured using the GeForce Experience or Raptr optimizer.

I've tried using [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) but that turned up nothing.  [AppCrashView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/app_crash_view.html) diagnosed the crashes and point at Steam2.dll and MSVCR100.dll.  I'm not sure what to do next.

What else can I try to diagnose this problem?

Things I have tried:

- memtest86 v4 [passed]
- Disk error check [no problems]
- Graphics and Windows drivers [up to date]
- Turn off anti-virus and game overlays
- Prime95 [stress test causing CPUTIN ~ 110C but core temps ~45C]
- Cleaned the hardware
- Ran `sfc /scannow` [no integrity violations]

My hardware and software setup has been the same for years.  Last March I added the SSD and did a full reinstall.

- Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 64bit
- Athlon II X3 450 (overclocked 15% using BIOS EZ Overclocking)
- Samsung SSD 840 EVO (as C: for the system)
- Western Digital WD20EZRX (as D: for games and media)
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560
- ASRock M3A770DE motherboard
- G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series 2 x 4GB
- Antec EarthWatts Green EA-430D

Comment: This is getting downvotes and votes to close.  Could people explain why?  I've already dug up AppCrashView as an investigative tool myself, that's exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Steam overlay is at fault.  I turned it off and now 3DMark works and Borderlands: TPS has stopped crashing.

Long answer: I learned about [AppCrashView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/app_crash_view.html) from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/218701/22550).  Running it revealed Steam2.dll was at fault for several of the Borderlands crashes.  Previously, Raptr's overlay had caused problems so I'd turned it off.  So I tried turning off Steam's overlay.  Voila!

It would be nice to know how to fix Steam overlay, but I'm just happy my games aren't crashing.